# Cuentas atrás en java

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación que me haga una cuenta atrás en java y no sé como conseguir que me realice la cuenta atrás desde 60 hasta 0. Este es mi código

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Referenciamos el elemento Button mediante su id y lo asignamos a la
    // variable de instancia
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    // Referenciamos el elemento TextView mediante su id y lo asignamos a la

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // Creamos un evento para cuando interactuemos con el botón
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(30000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    counter++;
                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    textView.setText("Cuenta atrás agotada");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan. Puedes pulsar en [edit] para especificar qué problema concreto tienes o qué has intentado?  Veo tu codigo pero no veo donde intentas que vaya de 60 a 0. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info . Un saludo

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema o dificultad que tienes con este código que muestras? ¿hay un error? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error exacto? ¿un comportamiento inesperado? ¿cuál es?

Comment: mi código funciona bien, pero hace la cuenta atras de un minuto de la siguiente forma (-1,-2-3-4...-59) y yo quiero que haga desde 60 hasta 0 (59,58,57..0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas agregar una variable `counter`, usando la clase [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) debes definir:

```
new CountDownTimer(60000,1000)
```

que determina que el conteo se realizará cada segundo (1000 ms) a partir de 60 segundos (60000 ms) hacia su finalización en 0 segundos, por lo tanto simplemente realiza esta operación `(millisUntilFinished / 1000)` para mostrar el valor en segundos en lugar de milisegundos y mostrar el valor del contador:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(60000,1000){

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    //textView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    //counter++;
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf((millisUntilFinished / 1000)));

                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    textView.setText("Cuenta atrás agotada");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

De esta forma tu contador funcionaría como lo deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Da la sensación que has cogido [el ejemplo del API de Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) sin entender cómo funciona:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

La forma de usarlo sería algo como (no lo he probado):

```
final long duracionTotal= 60 * 1000; //milisegundos
final long tiempoEntreTicks= 1000; //un segundo
new CountDownTimer(duracionTotal, tiempoEntreTicks) {
    public void onTick(long milisegHastaFin) {
        long segundosPasados = (duracionTotal - milisegHastaFin) /1000;
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(segundosPasados));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textView.setText("Cuenta atrás agotada");
    }
}.start()
```